# Declaration of entities in EclipseLink JPA native queries

Tags: eclipselink

Does EclipseLink support the declaration of entities in JPA native queries?

I am looking for something like this

```
sess.createSQLQuery("SELECT {cat.*}, {m.*}  FROM CATS c, CATS m WHERE c.MOTHER_ID = m.ID")
 .addEntity("cat", Cat.class)
 .addEntity("mother", Cat.class)
```

The code example is using the Hibernate API and I wonder whether something similar is possible using the unwrapped Eclipse JPA query.

Comment: What is the purpose of the above query?  Is it not just a JPQL query "select c, m from Cats c, Cats m where c.mother=m"?  If this is meant to be a native SQL query, then JPA supports building entities from it using the ResultSetMapping http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/SqlResultSetMapping.html

Comment: Yes, native SQL query. SQLResultSetMapping can't be used programmatically or can it be?